# How can I overload any arbitrary binary or unary operator for a class?

Tags: matlab, class, operator-overloading

Suppose you have a class inheriting an array `x`, adding some parameters `p`:

```
classdef test
    properties
       x
       p
    end
    methods
       function t=calculate(t)
           [t.x,t.p]=calc(x,p);
       end
       function t=plus(t1,t2)
           t.x=t1.x+t2.x;
       end
   end
end
```

It is known how to overload binary operators, such as `plus`, `mtimes`, `minus`, etc.. How can I enable overloading for **any** binary vectorized operator, or eventually, any unary operator such as `mean`, `abs`, `max`, etc., in order to be applied directly over the vector `x`? For example, how can I have `S = mean(S);` be equivalent to `S.x = mean(S.x);`?

Comment: Maybe this similar post could help you: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/275199-how-to-overload-all-functions-and-operators-of-a-new-class

Comment: Yeah, i checked that before writing the question. It is still very weird to write `S0.oper(@plus,(S2.oper(@minus,(S0.oper(@abs)))))` or something similar for simple arithmetic operations with classes instead of `S0+S2-abs(S0)`.....

Comment: You mention "inheriting". Does that mean `test` is a subclass of a class that contains `x`? If so, does that superclass implement any of the built-in operators?

Comment: I keep the problem both if `x` is a class with built in operators implemented, or if `x` is a standard array. We can safely consider the last case.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, it sounds like you want your new class `test` to simply inherit all of the binary and unary methods defined for the class of the property `x` (and operate on property `x` when invoking them) so that you don't have to redefine them all yourself.

If this is what you want, then I think the only feasible way to do something like it is to actually use *inheritance* and make your class `test` a [subclass](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/subclass-syntax.html) of the class of property `x`. Considering the simple case where `x` is just a [`double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html), a good example of subclassing the built-in `double` type can be found [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/built-in-subclasses-with-properties.html). Adapting that example to yours, here's one way you could implement your class `test`:

```
classdef test < double

  properties
    p
  end

  methods
    function obj = test(x, p)
      if (nargin < 2)
        p = 0;
        if (nargin < 1)
          x = 0;
        end
      end
      obj@double(x);
      obj.p = p;
    end

    function sref = subsref(obj, s)
      switch s(1).type
        case '.'
          switch s(1).subs
            case 'p'
              sref = obj.p;
            case 'x'
              x = double(obj);
              if (length(s) < 2)
                sref = x;
              elseif (length(s) > 1) && strcmp(s(2).type, '()')
                sref = subsref(x, s(2:end));
              end
            otherwise
              error('Not a supported indexing expression')
          end
        case '()'
          x = double(obj);
          newx = subsref(x, s(1:end));
          sref = test(newx, obj.p);
        case '{}'
          error('Not a supported indexing expression')
      end
    end

    function obj = subsasgn(obj, s, b)
      switch s(1).type
        case '.'
          switch s(1).subs
            case 'p'
              obj.p = b;
            case 'x'
              if (length(s) < 2)
                obj = test(b, obj.p);
              elseif (length(s) > 1) && strcmp(s(2).type, '()')
                x = double(obj);
                newx = subsasgn(x, s(2:end), b);
                obj = test(newx, obj.p);
              end
            otherwise
              error('Not a supported indexing expression')
          end
        case '()'
          x = double(obj);
          newx = subsasgn(x, s(1), b);
          obj = test(newx, obj.p);
        case '{}'
          error('Not a supported indexing expression')
      end
    end

    function disp(obj)
      fprintf('p:');
      disp(obj.p);
      fprintf('x:');
      disp(double(obj));
    end
  end

end
```

There is one caveat: the result you get from using `double` operators and methods on objects of class `test` will return results of class `double`, not `test` as you would like. To get the behavior you want you will have to reassign the result to property `x` each time, as in the following examples:

```
>> a = test(1:3, pi)  % Create an object with p = pi, and x = [1 2 3]

a = 
p:   3.141592653589793
x:     1     2     3

>> a.x = -a  % Unary operation on a, and reassignment to x

a = 
p:   3.141592653589793
x:    -1    -2    -3

>> a.x = a+4  % Binary operation and reassignment

a = 
p:   3.141592653589793
x:     3     2     1

>> a.x = mean(a)  % Another unary operation and reassignment

a = 
p:   3.141592653589793
x:     2
```